# How do I change each instance X rotation at different moment

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a camera, that I move along the X axis, and I want to rotate each instance of the K logo subtracting the x position of each instance to the actual camera position, to make it more dynamic, right now every K logo are rotating at the same time, not sure how to solve this with geometry nodes :( some help?

[image: geometry nodes test]

Answer (score 2):

I finally sorted out :)! now it works :D!!

[image: finally!]